# Sprites not displaying after Thread to Runnable switch

Tags: java, android

I switched a thread from extending Thread to implementing Runnable (implementing Runnable is better practice, right?) so when I called surfaceCreated I went from:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    createSprites();
    gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
    gameLoopThread.start();
}
```

to:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    createSprites();
    gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
    gameLoopThread.run();
}
```

as the start() method is not included in the Runnable interface. However, once I switched this, my sprites no longer displayed. This is the run() method:

```
public void run() {
    Canvas c;
    while (running) {
        c = null;
        try {
            c = view.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (mPauseLock) {
                view.onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                view.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }

        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            while (mPaused) {
                try {
                    mPauseLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It gets called during both scenarios, but sprites only display when I call start() instead of directly calling run(). Could someone explain why this is?

Comment: *There is nothing special about the `run` method* - and when you call a method, the code after the method call doesn't execute until the method returns, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't start a `Thread` by calling `gameLoopThread.run()` for a `Runnable` (or even by calling `run()` for a `Thread`).
You have to pass your `Runnable` instance to a `Thread` instance and call `start()` for that `Thread`.

For example :

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    createSprites();
    gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
    Thread t = new Thread(gameLoopThread);
    t.start();
}
```